# No puedo conseguir obtener ID de <tr>, jquery

Tags: jquery, table

estoy tratando de manipular la id de un tr de una tabla, que tengo en el html.

```
$('body').on('click', '#tablausuarios tr', function() {
    var idtr = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(idtr);
})
```

El HTML es así

```
<table id="tablausuarios">
        <thead>
            <td class="campo">Dato 1 Title</td>
            <td class="campo">Dato 2 Title</td>
            <td class="campo">Dato 3 Title</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="1">
                <td class="campo">Dato 1</td>
                <td class="campo">Dato 2</td>
                <td class="campo">Dato 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2">
                <td class="campo">Dato 1</td>
                <td class="campo">Dato 2</td>
                <td class="campo">Dato 3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Cuando hago `console.log(idtr);` me tira el "undefined". Debería traerme el ID del TR q estoy haciendo click.

Xq este error?

Answer (score 1):

En el `thead` debes agregar un `tr` tambien, para optimización de tu código, puedes utilizar la clase que usas para los `td` ya que al hacer click realmente lo haces sobre este y no sobre `tr`, te dejo como puedes modificar tu js

```
$('#tablausuarios td.campo').on('click', function() {
    var idtr = $(this).parent('tr').attr('id');
    console.log(idtr);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('body').on('click', '#tablausuarios tr', function() {
    var idtr = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(idtr);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablausuarios">
        <thead>
            <td class="campo">Dato 1 Title</td>
            <td class="campo">Dato 2 Title</td>
            <td class="campo">Dato 3 Title</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="1">
                <td class="campo">Dato 1</td>
                <td class="campo">Dato 2</td>
                <td class="campo">Dato 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="2">
                <td class="campo">Dato 1</td>
                <td class="campo">Dato 2</td>
                <td class="campo">Dato 3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Te comento que tu codigo si funciona, puede ser que nada mas te falte la libreria de JQuery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Nada mas te va a mandar undefined en el thead, pero lo puede solucionar agregando un ID mas.